# Disable sorting of COMPREPLY in bash complete function

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a list of words that should be present in the order of appearance in completion to a certain key, but bash seems to be internally sorting what is assigned to `COMPREPLY` array. How to avoid that?

Example:

```
_comm() {
    _init_completion -s -n : || return
    case $prev in
        -a) COMPREPLY=(zxy abcdef tyuu fgsfds)
            ;;
    esac
}
complete -F _comm comm
```

If you run this code, bash should complete

```
$ comm -a
```

with

```
abcdef fgsfds tyuu zxy
```

i.e. sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Bash 4.4 you can use `nosort` option. In your example change the last line to:

```
complete -o nosort -F _comm comm
```

and you should get completions without alphabetical sorting.

**Important note: options** (specified with `-o`) **must precede functions** (`-F`). That’s why coderofsalvation’s code didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* be achieved by modifying the complete command:

```
complete -F _comm comm
```

into:

```
complete -F _comm comm -o nosort
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html):

however I didn't get this to work on bash 4 :/

It seems it is a documented, yet not implemented feature of controlling readline's variable `rl_sort_completion_matches`.

[More info](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html)