# Why does `complete` sort options even with `nosort`?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I can't get [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333921/3645) to work in Bash 4.4.20 (default shell in Ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ complete -o nosort -W '--color=auto --color=always --color=never' mycommand
$ mycommand --<Tab>
--color=always  --color=auto    --color=never
```

Setting `COMPREPLY` in a function gives the same result:

```
_mycommand() {
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '--color=auto --color=always --color=never' -- "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
}

complete -o nosort -F _mycommand mycommand
```

`man bash` mentions the `nosort` option, so it should be supported. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by [`completion-ignore-case`](https://lists.defectivebydesign.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-05/msg00034.html):

```
$ bind "set completion-ignore-case off"
$ bind -V | grep ignore-case
completion-ignore-case is set to `off'
$ complete -o nosort -W '--color=auto --color=always --color=never' mycommand
$ mycommand --<Tab>
--color=auto    --color=always  --color=never
```

Looks like the fix is not in Bash 4.4.20.